# Why that sound does not work on mobile?

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a sound during an event. It works with PC, but not with mobile. Any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http:///music.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
});
```

Comment: ugh sounds are annoying

Comment: @Yoda please let me know whether my answer acceptable for you so i could update it if needed )

Answer (score 3):

You can't auto-play audio on mobile, it has to be started from a touch event, because each sound playing on mobile device **requires** a user interaction, his "OK" or his "Go for it" by touching an element on your page. This can be the built-in Audio player controls or any click or **touch** event handler bound to your elements. **Once an interaction is done**, the file is downloaded to your device and you can do all audio things you want to do.

**NOTE:** That's restriction applied for IOS ( as @Josh1billion hightlighted in comments).

Comment: Hum, vous thank pour vos explications. En fait, je voulais jouer le son après un certain temps, il est donc pas possible :(

Comment: @Yoda Which mobile platform are you using?  What Andriy says is true as a limitation for iOS, but Android didn't have the same restriction last I knew when developing HTML5 games for mobile.  That was admittedly about 3-4 years ago, though, so it's possible things could have changed since then.

Comment: @Josh1billion i use IOS. While I have not tested on android.

Comment: @Yoda Ahh, yeah iOS will give you issues then.  I ran into that when developing mobile games, they would never work right on iOS because Apple intentionally disabled sound unless in reaction to a user-generated event, making HTML5 games useless on iOS.  It supposedly worked in older versions of iOS until a few years ago, and people speculate Apple disabled it so they could make more money from games on their app store instead of letting their users play HTML5 games.  Greedy if you ask me.

Comment: Merci pour tout @ Josh1billion Nice information for me.